# GemFire Select * Query with index returns inconsistent results

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, oql

I have a GemFire Query, something like "`SELECT * FROM /someregion WHERE fieldX IN SET('123')`".

This query returns inconsistent results.  For example, it will return the same record many times, etc. If I change the query to "`SELECT key FROM /someregion WHERE fieldX IN SET('123')`", then I get correct results. I also get correct results if I specify the column name(s) rather than '*'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have duplicated entries within the `Region` with different keys?, have you tried adding the `DISTINCT` keyword to the `SELECT *` query?. Maybe sharing a small reproducible scenario on `GitHub` or somewhere else might help in troubleshooting this.

Comment: I also echo what Juan has asked you, especially providing a small example (in a _GitHub_ Repo) reproducing the issue, would be very helpful.  In addition, what type of OQL Index are you using?

Comment: are you usng Pdx serilization or its clear data ?